# How do I turn any "Text" into "Value" in Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DFqKW.png)

According to example picture, I have "value" in H2 equal to 10 and I have "Text" in J2 equal to "H2*5", all I needed is the answer in L2 of 50. The question is How do I turn a text in J2 into a value?

I have already try to put "=" symbol before this text as shown in L2 but it seems not working. Is there any solution for that? Thank you very much for you response.

Comment: Why not you use `=H2*5` in `L2` cell?

Comment: It is just the example sir. Yes, you can use "=H2+5" in L2 cell for the simple solution. The real problem I have is about How we turn any text into value, which I still don't know.

Answer (score 0):

You can try splitting then indirect() function. Try-

```
=INDIRECT(INDEX(SPLIT(J2,"*"),1,1))*INDEX(SPLIT(J2,"*"),1,2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution sir. This solution is working correctly as I needed, but the problem is it seems working in the particular case like this one, which have two variations and "*" conjunction. I still curious that Is there way to turn any "text" into "value" in the simple way as any function in excel or spreadsheet.

Comment: @user22502339 When you are mixing number and cell reference then it is complicated. If it was only number like `1+1` or `2*2` or `3/3` or `9-3` then it would be easier to evaluate.

Comment: `but the problem is it seems working in the particular case like this one, which have two variations and "*" conjunction.` The question specified a given scenario using two variations and "*" conjunction and _this is a good answer to that question_. If you _really_ want to know `Is there way to turn any "text" into "value"`, then I would respectfully suggest that you need to post a new question on that topic taking into account the various configurations and conjunctions and the expected answers in each case.

Answer (score 0):

There are no simple ways of evaluating a text string as a formula in Google Sheets. QUERY can be abused to perform arbitrary calculations within its *select* string, and so if an appropriate REGEXEXTRACT expression can be generated to parse a text string into its individual elements these can potentially be fed into QUERY. The following formula will give the result for any text input of the form 'Cell/Operator/Value' as you've given in the example, but to make this work for any input will be complex (e.g. you need to detect if an individual element is a cell reference and use INDIRECT for these but not others, etc etc...)

```
=let(
splitstring,regexextract(J2,"(.+)(\+|\-|\*|\/)(.+)"),
query(query(,"select "&indirect(choosecols(splitstring,1))&choosecols(splitstring,2)&choosecols(splitstring,3),0),"offset 1",0))
```